# error comparing two bytes memory

Tags: contract-development, remix, bytes, data-types

I am testing a smart contract in Remix and I get the following error when trying to compare two bytes memory using "==":

TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types bytes memory and bytes memory.

This is my code :

```
function removeCertificate(bytes memory CertificateHash, address holder) external 
    isAProvider 
    isTheProviderOrHimself(holder, CertificateHash) 
{
    address provider = _CertificatesPerHolder[holder]._CertificateFromProvider[CertificateHash];
    bytes[] memory listOfCert = _CertificatesPerHolder[holder]._ListOfCertificates;
    
    for(uint i=0; i < listOfCert.length; i++){
        if(CertificateHash == listOfCert[i]){
            ArrayRemoveResize(i, _CertificatesPerHolder[holder]._ListOfCertificates);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    delete _CertificatesPerHolder[holder]._CertificateFromProvider[CertificateHash];
    
    emit _RemoveCertificateIdEvent(provider, holder);

}
```

I get the error at line : " if(CertificateHash == listOfCert[i]){"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`listOfCert` is of type `bytes`, `listOfCert[i]` is one element of those bytes. `CertificateHash` is of type `bytes`. So you cannot compare `bytes` to a single `byte`. Remix must have drawn your attention to that.

If you want to compare two `bytes` values, you can either check that they are of equal lengths, and if they are then proceed to loop through the elements one by one. But since two equal byte sequences will have equal `keccak256` hashes, a more gas-efficient way to compare two byte sequences in Solidity is to [compare their hashes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/types.html#bytes-and-string-as-arrays):

```
bytes memory a = hex"00112233";
bytes memory b = hex"00112233";
bool areEqual = keccak256(a) == keccak256(b);
```

You could even try:

```
bool areEqual = a.length == b.length && keccak256(a) == keccak256(b);
```

This might bring some gains if you will often be comparing long bytes sequences of unequal lengths, at the cost of extra code.

Best would be to implement all three methods and compare how gas usage varies for different scenarios, and choose the best one to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Actually I wanted listOfCert to be an array of "bytes" which is itself an array of "byte", I guess I was trying to implement a two dimensional array of "byte" where the first dimension is of dynamic length...

Comment: Thats exactly my problem, it seems when we storing bytes in a array of bytes ,it stored them as byte, so how can we create an array which has elements of bytes, instead of byte??